# Retrieve WP system tray (notification area) height

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, height, system-tray, notification-area

For some control layout calculations, I need to know the height of the notification area. Sure, I know that it equals 32 pixels in portrait mode in WP 7/8/8.1, but it's not a good idea to hard code this value for the future releases of the OS. How can I retrieve this value on-the-fly in a Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. We can determine the vertical offset for the main layout root control (generally a Grid), and it will be the height of the system tray:

```cs
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GeneralTransform gt = LayoutRoot.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
    Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    double systemTrayHeight = offset.Y;
}
```

Comment: This technique will fail when the page is set to support landscape orientation. As answered by @RandomEngy - hardcoding `32`, `72` and taking the `ScaleFactor` into account would be the best route.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get Height of notification area by Code.

its Standards are `Pre-Defined`.
`System Tray` is the small tiny bar across the top of the Phone screen. It displays in Portrait mode. When your application is set in Portrait mode, the `height` of the System Tray becomes `32 pixel` and when the application is set in `Landscape mode`, the width of the System Tray becomes `72 pixel`. This is as per the UI Design Guidelines and Interaction Guideline of Windows Phone 7.

You can get more information  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray)  about what is accessible

Comment: "You can't get" is not our answer :). See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
double contentScaleFactor = (double)Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100;
double systemTrayHeight = 32 / contentScaleFactor;
```

Or 72 for landscape orientation. Phones like the Lumia 1520 scale the app content up, so you have to adjust for it.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but if we talk about the actual height on the screen. I needed the height I can use as the values for the Height/MinHeight/Maxheight properties. I needed to calculate those 32 pixels dynamically because it can be changed in later releases of the OS. In fact, you hard-coded the same 32 pixels in your code.

Comment: Our approach to the system tray was to set the opacity to 0 and place a shim at the top of the page, so turning it on and off didn't move content around. With your answer we'd have to set opacity to 1, wait for a layout update, then record the offset and set back to 0. I think the "32" number is not quite as likely to change since that number is DPI-independent. I don't think there's a better way of getting the system tray size (while avoiding a scouting layout pass).

Comment: In any case, it's an interesting idea "to set opacity to 1, wait for a layout update, then record the offset". Can you show us some working code? How do you wait - using a timer, or another technique?

Comment: Well doing that sounded not great to me. You'd probably subscribe to the SizeChanged event on your root element if you wanted that.